# bazel shared librarys and --no-as-needed

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, bazel, bazel-rules

I have a complicated build, where I need to pass `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to the linker for a few shared libraries. This seems to be impossible using stock bazel rules like `cc_library`. I've created a simplified example to demonstrate the problem:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "libmylib1.so",
    srcs = ["lib1.cc"],
    linkshared = True,
)

cc_binary(
    name = "libmylib2.so",
    srcs = ["lib2.cc"],
    linkshared = True,
)

cc_library(
    name = "mylib",
    srcs = ["libmylib1.so", "libmylib2.so"],
    deps = [":libmylib1.so", ":libmylib2.so"],
    linkopts = ["-Wl,--no-as-needed"], # Appears after srcs
)

cple_cc_test(
    name = "hello_world",
    srcs = [
        "hello_world.cc",
    ],
    deps = [":mylib"],
    linkopts = ["-Wl,--no-as-needed"], # Appears after dependencies
)
```

The libraries in question are single functions. It's unimportant.

When we see the generated command line:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/collect2 \
   -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/liblto_plugin.so \
   -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper \
   -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccZuRDxx.res \
   -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc \
   -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s \
   -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread \
   -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc \
   -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc \
   -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s \
   --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed \
   -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
   -pie -z now -fuse-ld=lld -z relro \
   -o bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/test/build/hello_world \
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o \
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o \
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbeginS.o \
   -Lbazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/_solib_linux_x86_64/_U_S_Stest_Sbuild_Cmylib___Utest_Sbuild \
   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 \
   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu \
   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib \
   -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
   -L/lib/../lib \
   -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
   -L/usr/lib/../lib \
   -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../.. \
   -rpath $ORIGIN/../../_solib_linux_x86_64/_U_S_Stest_Sbuild_Cmylib___Utest_Sbuild \
bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/test/build/_objs/hello_world/hello_world.o \
# THE LINE BELOW IS OF INTEREST #
   -lmylib1 -lmylib2 --no-as-needed \
   --no-as-needed -lstdc++ -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state \
   -lpthread -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state \
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtendS.o \
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

What I need is `--no-as-needed -lmylib1 -lmylib2` ...

Do I need to trick bazel by putting a fake dependency before the library dependency?! Bazel is trying to be too helpful here. Advice is appreciated.

Comment: Does `alwayslink = true` solve the problem for you? (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.alwayslink)

Comment: I played with `alwayslink = True`, and it has no effect on the shared library. (The documentation does mention "object files") It doesn't emit `--no-as-needed`, and the overall complicated build that inspired this example still fails to run.

Comment: I even created by own toolchain to pass the `-Wl,--no-as-needed` flag when linking, and bazel shunts them all to the end of the link line. It's perverse.